# Excel How can I direct columns by their headline?

Tags: excel, match, formula

Currently I have a huge formula in my excel sheet:

> =SUM(SUMIF(INDIRECT(A9&"!$F:$F"),"working";INDIRECT(A9&"!$B:$B"))+SUMIF(INDIRECT(A9&"!$F:$F");"Open";INDIRECT(A9&"!$B:$B"))+SUMIF(INDIRECT(A9&"!$F:$F");"internal",INDIRECT(A9&"!$B:$B"))+(SUMIF(INDIRECT(A9&"!$F:$F"),"finished";INDIRECT(A9&"!$AP:$AP"))))

In A9 is the name of the excel sheet that the formula has to use. So for example in A3 there's '20140612', so it has to use the excel sheet with the name '20140612'. Furthermore it sums up some values depending on some conditions.

My question is: I would like to direct the columns in the other sheets by their headlines, not their positions in the sheet. So for example le column AP doesn't always has to be in the position AP, but has always the headline 'Points'.

Can you think of an adaption of the formula that can direct the column by their headline?
I though of the MATCH formula. But I'm not to sure where I have to put this in.

Comment: What are the names of your two headers in columns F and B?  Are the headings in row 1 of your sheet named in A9?

Comment: The names of the headers in the columns are 'Points' and 'Progress'. They are not named in my overview excel sheet, but can I also adress them by their headers? So that I can include in my formula (see above) not the columns by using AQ:AQ for example, but by using 'the column with the header 'Points'? The header will ALWAYS be 'Points'! @MarkFitzgerald

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest answer would be to use [named ranges](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/define-named-cell-references-or-ranges-HP005201536.aspx) within your sheet.  In this way you could name a range (currently in column AP) as 'Points', change your formula to use 'Points' instead of '$AP:$AP' & if you move your points data about the formulas would be unchanged.

If you are planning to keep changing your header row values then you could use [HLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/mac-excel-help/hlookup-function-HA102927735.aspx?CTT=1) to match up the header column probably in conjunction with [MATCH & INDEX](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/office-online-help/look-up-values-with-vlookup-index-or-match-HA104133670.aspx?CTT=1).

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. The problem with your first proposal is, that I can't edit the excel sheet with the directet columns. I get an export every week and the goal is to have the desired data without adapting the export. Can you maybe give more details about your second recommendation? I think this will work, but I'm not to sure how to use it right. @amelvin

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about the usage of `MATCH()`, it's worth thinking of it as half of a `VLOOKUP()` or `HLOOKUP()`, i.e. it's the bit that finds the row or column containing the value you're searching for, then you can use `INDEX()` to get that row / column from a range you specify.

So, if you know that one of your column headings is `"Points"`, then you could find it by using:

```
=MATCH("Points", A1:Z1, FALSE)
```

...which would return 10 if `"Points"` were the heading of column J for example. If you wanted to then use that column for a lookup, you can use `OFFSET()` to define that column as a range to use for a lookup, so let's say I wanted to find the text `"foo"` in the "Points" column, I could use:

```
=MATCH("foo", OFFSET(A1:Z1000, 0, MATCH("Points", A1:Z1, FALSE) - 1, 1000, 1), false)
```

... which uses the column index I found before as an input to `OFFSET()` in order to dynamically reference `J1:J1000` and then search for `"foo"` in that column.

For your example in the question, rather than `A1:Z1000` you could use a call to `INDIRECT()` that would return the entire range of interest from your source sheet.